# Deserialize JSON using Retrofit to Room Embedded Class

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room, gson

I'm receiving this JSON from my server. My requirement is slightly different than usual use-cases hence this question. In my case I'm using `@Embedded` provided by Room library.

```
[
{
    "id": 105,
    "title": "Clear notification",
    "message": "Opening the app should automatically clear the notifications",
    "klass": "Demo",
    "priority": 0,
    "timestamp": "2017-09-03T07:20:56.130500Z",
    "teacher": "ABC",
    "attachments": []
},
{
    "id": 104,
    "title": "Attachment",
    "message": "File upload take 1",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Technology List.txt",
            "url": "https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/",
            "type": "text/plain",
            "size": 954
        }
    ]
}
```

]

The POJO's for the above JSON. I'm de-serializing JSON to `FeedWithAttachment` class.

```
public class FeedWithAttachment {
    @NotNull @Embedded
    public Feed feed; 
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "feedId", entity = Attachment.class)       
    public List<Attachment> attachments;

}
```

My Feed class:

```
data class Feed(
        @PrimaryKey @SerializedName("id")
        var id: Long = 0,

        @SerializedName("title")
        var title: String = "",

        @SerializedName("message")
        var message: String = "",
)
```

My attachment class:

```
data class Attachment(
        @PrimaryKey @SerializedName("id")
        var attachmentId: Int = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var url: String = "",
        var type: String = "",
        var size: Long = 0,
        @Transient
        var feedId: Long = 0
)
```

If we put `List<Attachment` in the `Feed` model then it works as expected. Unfortunately my requirements are such that I need another class called as `FeedWithAttachment`.

Retrofit:

```
interface FeedService {
    public Call<List<FeedWithAttachment>> getFeeds();
}
```

---

**The problem**

I'm getting `FeedWithAttachment` in the response where `feed` is `null` and `attachments` is as expected.

Comment: what you did in API call response? post your answer.

Comment: @MehulKabaria I'm getting `FeedWithAttachment` where `feed` is `null` and `attachments` is as expected.

Comment: You appear to be trying to use the same Java classes to represent a server response and a database structure. Those things are completely independent: the server can change the nature of the served JSON, and you are limited to relational structures on the database (and the particular subset of SQLite features that Room supports). IMHO, you should not be bothering trying to use the same classes for these, as you are not necessarily able to use the same classes for them in the future. Have separate classes modeling your server response and your database structure.

Comment: @CommonsWare I always thought of having same class to represent server response and database structure cause it made my life easier. Now I know it's not a best practice. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In an ideal world, they would be the same class. In an ideal world, I would have hair. :-) Beyond the natural "impedance mismatch" between a JSON-style tree structure and a corresponding relational structure, in many cases, you don't control the server, and the server team might decide to totally reorganize their JSON (e.g., to better support iOS clients, Web clients, ...). Given uncontrolled changes on one side (JSON) and structural limitations on the other (relational/Room), IMHO you're better served modeling them separately.

Comment: Great. Right now I have control over server and Android cause it's own company I could do this. But I agree with your point.

Answer (score 0):

When you write feed variable in FeedWithAttachment, retrofit try to find "feed" in keys in json.
each variable name defined in class must exist in json's key.
you use this class:

```
public class FeedWithAttachment {
    int id;
    String title;
    String message;
    String klass;
    int priority;
    String timestamp;
    String teacher;

    List<Attachment> attachments;
}
```

and Attachment.class :

```
public class Attachment{
    int id;
    String name;
    String url;
    String type;
    int size;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this solution. But can we have something where we embed the `Feed` in the `FeedWithAttachment`

Comment: @AkshayChordiya As far as I know, it's not possible.